# How can I read the message properties of an Activemq.Advisory message from a Python3.7 application

Tags: python, activemq-classic

I am using paho.mqtt.client on a Raspberry Pi4 in Python3.7 to publish messages to an ActiveMQ instance running locally. I would like to monitor the status of the consumer of my queues so that I can raise an alert (to a Siemens PLC using snap7) if the subscriber goes offline. When I use a program like QueueExplorer, manually, I can look at a message in the 'Advisory' topic for my queue and from it's Custom property, I can see the 'consumer Count' and determine that there is an active consumer.

[image: QueueExplorer message properties]

I need to get this information into my app but unfortunately MQTT messages don't have 'Properties' that can be accessed by paho.mqtt.client, and Activemq 'Advisory' messages don't have any data in the 'body' of the message, so I have to find another method of reading the 'consumer Count'. I have looked at STOMP but cannot find any examples of reading message 'Properties'. Any suggestions please?

This is the code I would need if I was using the CMS API from the ActiveMQ-CPP Library, but I believe that this is in C++ and that is not my world! :-)

```
void AdvisoryProducer::onMessage( const cms::Message* message ) {

   if( message->getCMSType() == "Advisory" ) {

       std::cout << "Received an Advisory Message!" << std::endl;

       if( message->propertyExists( "consumerCount" ) ) {

           std::string consumerCount = message->getStringProperty( "consumerCount" );
           std::cout << "Number of Consumers = " << consumerCount << std::endl;

           // Do Something Meaningful here....
       }

   } else {
       std::cout << "Received a Non-Advisory Message!" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

This is the code that I am trying to use at the moment but instead of subscribing to the topic, it creates a new queue!

```
import time
import sys

import stomp

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message)
    def on_message(self, message):
        print('received a message "%s"' % message)
        print(message.body)
        print(message.cmd)
        print(message.headers[''])

TOPIC = 'ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Topic.xbox_001'

conn = stomp.Connection()
conn.set_listener('', MyListener())
conn.connect('admin', 'password', wait=True)
conn.subscribe(destination=TOPIC, id='1', ack='auto')

time.sleep(3600)
conn.disconnect()
```

Before I run the code, I can see the existing topic that is created when the  'xbox_001' topic is created, and messages are generated in the advisory topic when subscribers connect etc. so that is working.

[image: Consumer Topic]

But when I run the code, it creates a new queue (and an advisory topic) instead of subscribing to the existing topic!

[image: New Queue]

Comment: What STOMP client are you using from your Python application?

Comment: I'm using stomp.py V7.0.0

Comment: Try using `TOPIC = 'topic/ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Topic.xbox_001'`. I believe STOMP clients need to use `queue/` or `topic/` prefix to tell the broker which semantics to use since the STOMP protocol itself makes no such distinctions.

Answer (score 0):

I FINALLY managed to sort out the issue, it was a simple (but annoying) string/path formatting problem. Unlike any other code in the history of programing EVER!, the path is a combination of '/' and '.' delimitators, and despite the fact that the file structure clearly has ''Topics' not 'topic' as the root, the path needed to be..... wait for it.... :-)

```
TOPIC = '/topic/ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Topic.xbox_001'
```

The mind boggles...

For completeness, here is the final code.

```
import time
import sys

import stomp

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message)
    def on_message(self, message):
        print('received a message "%s"' % message)
        print(message.body)
        print(message.cmd)
        print(message.headers['consumerCount'])

TOPIC = '/topic/ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Topic.xbox_001'
conn = stomp.Connection()
conn.set_listener('', MyListener())
conn.connect('admin', 'password', wait=True)
conn.subscribe(destination=TOPIC, id='1', ack='auto')

time.sleep(3600)
conn.disconnect()
```